# see only those question with unaccepted answer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions, bountied-tab

Is there any filter option in Stack Overflow. so that I can see only those questions which are having some answers (or no answers) with unaccepted answer. So that I can try to help OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) is your friend:

[image]

So what you need is just type `hasaccepted:0` into the search box to get what you ask for, then sort by newest. [Shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted:0).

Unlike the Unanswered tab, this will also give questions that have upvoted answers.

The only downside is that being a search, it's limited to 5000 results which means the oldest question you will find is ~24 hours old.

Comment: As you defined the shortcut, So when I want to get list of my favorite tag questions then should I make changes in the URL to get the above question list?

Comment: You can see only one tag at a time with such filter, e.g. [JavaScript questions with no accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a0%20%5bjavascript%5d)